# Make yakuake outputting correct characters

Tags: arch-linux, locale

I have some files that using japanese, korean and chinese characters in their filename, this is the example filename

```
栗山千明 - おいしい季節決定的三分間.rar
```

but when i tried to `ls -w1 *.rar` in the `yakuake` console, it shows as:

```
æ å±±åæ - ããããå­£ç¯æ±ºå®çä¸åé.rar
```

my `locale` output:

```
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm using `Ubuntu Mono` font for the console..

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that the console you're using is set up to display hi-bit characters as iso 8859-1 characters instead of as UTF-8 characters.  Now the way to change a given terminal to use UTF-8 instead of ISO 8859-1 depends on the exact terminal being used:

- xterm is told to display utf-8 characters via the `-u8` command line option when launching or via the XTERM_LOCALE environmental variable
- Gnome terminal sets the character set to display characters via Terminal -> Set Character Encoding
- If logging in to a UNIX machine from PuTTY, change the character encoding by setting Window -> Translation before logging in
- If not in X and at a Linux console, the `setfont` command is the one to use, e.g. `setfont -m utf-8` or, on older systems, the `mapscrn` command.  More information: http://linux.die.net/man/8/setfont
- If using some other terminal to get to the console, the procedure will be different

Similar discussion: [Characters encodings supported by more, cat and less](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/characters-encodings-supported-by-more-cat-and-less)

Comment: the encoding on `yakuake` is already UTF-8 (Manage Current Profile > Advanced > Encoding > UTF-8)

Comment: ah, by setting `export TERM='xterm -u8'` it works ^^ thanks

Comment: ah wait, i don't even do a thing (adding `export TERM`), this already work after restarting '___'