# Cat and Less give different output

Tags: terminal, cat, escape-characters, less

I executed the following command 
 

`# top > /home/user/top_output.txt` 

Nothing Happened for a while and then i pressed `Ctrl+C`. When i checked the file that was created, it had the contents in it. So i fired  `cat` command on it and it gave me this output. 
[image: cat output of the text file]

But when i tried the same thing with the `less` command i got this.

[image: less output of the files]

According to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78850/48509) the job of `Cat,less or More` is just to display the contents of the file not translating the encoding. Can someone please tell me what's happening  here?

P.S: I'm currently using Fedora 19

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The escape sequences `ESC [ ... m` are called [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). `top` sends them to your terminal to make it format output in color, bold, inverted text and so on. You never see these characters when running `top` but you see the resulting format. You could think of it as looking at a webpage in a browser - you don't see the `<html>...` formatting the content.

When dumping the output of `top` into a file, you are saving the non-printable escape sequences with everything else. Think of it as saving `view source` in your browser.

The default for `less` is to escape terminal control characters, displaying them in a printable form.

The default for `cat` is to pass them through to your terminal which interprets them and makes it look "normal".

Try `less -r /home/user/top_output.txt`

> ```
>    $ man less ...
>    -r or --raw-control-chars
>           Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  
>            The default is to display control characters using the caret
>            notation; for example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as 
>            "^A". Warning: when the -r option is used, less cannot keep 
>            track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends
>            on how the screen responds to each type of control
>            character).  Thus, various display problems may result, such
>            as long lines being split in the wrong place.
> ```

Compare to `cat -v /home/user/top_output.txt` which will escape non-printable characters.

Comment: the `cat -v` command gave me control characters as in `^[(B` and `^[m` in the output which was pretty garbled

Comment: thanks! `less -r` solved it.now its displaying in proper format. But i did'nt understand why that happened, as you see there are no special characters except `% :` and commas

Comment: When you run `top` in the terminal, you will see colors and other formatting (inverted text, bold etc). All these formats are caused by non-printable control-characters. So in your file there are lots of non-printable characters. `% : ,` are printable and have nothing to do with it.

Comment: `cat -v`: yes exactly, `-v` makes cat show you all the non-printable characters by escaping them. It is definitely garbled. This garble is what your terminal normally sees and interprets into color/formatting before displaying it to you.

Comment: When I try `less -r` on an export of the Windows 10 registry, I still get different looks compared to when using `cat`. The output from `cat` is human readable, while the output from `less -r` is all black and seemingly sporadically prints `<FF><FE>W` when I press the up and down arrows.